# Cohomological indices VS cup-length, Lusternik-Schnirelmann category, betti sum in critical point set theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, cohomology, symplectic-topology

Let $M$ be a (closed) manifold acted on by a compact Lie group $G$. For any characteristic class $\alpha \in H^*(BG)$, one can define a so-called cohomological index of $M$ as follows:
$$\text{ind}_{\alpha}M := 1+ \text{max} \lbrace k \geq 0 : f^*(\alpha^k) \neq 0 \rbrace,$$
where $f : M_G \to BG$ is the classifying map, and $M_G$ is the homotopy quotient $M \times EG / G$, $EG \to BG$ being the universal principal bundle of $G$.

This index enjoys several interesting properties (see for instance the book of Fadell and Rabinowitz on cohomological indices). In particular, it is interesting for the study of sublevel sets of $G$-invariant functions and their critical point sets. The following example (taken from Théret's thesis) illustrates this idea:

---

Consider the complex projective space $\mathbb{C} P^{n-1} = S^{2n-1} / S^1$. By a **conical** function $f: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ we mean an $S^1$-invariant function which is also homogeneous of degree $2$ with respect to the standard $\mathbb{C}^*$ action on each factor of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Any conical function $f$ induces a function $\overline{f} : \mathbb{C} P^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and conversely, any function on $\mathbb{C} P^n$ determines uniquely a conical function on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Note that any critical point of $f$ has critical value $0$ (by homogeneity), and appears as a whole cone in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Suppose that we are given a one-parameter family $$f : \mathbb{C}^n \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$$ of conical functions $f_t := f(.,t)$, and that $0$ is a regular value of $f$. Then the critical values of the projection $f^{-1}(0) \to [0,1]$ are precisely those values $t$ for which $f_t$ has a non-trivial critical point. We would like to study the change in the topology of the sublevel sets 
$$M_t := f_t^{-1}(-\infty, 0],$$
when $t$ varies.

First, in a neighbourhood of a regular value $t_0$, the sets $M_t$ are isotopic, (as well as their boundaries $\partial M := f_t^{-1}(0)$). As a consequence, any change in the homotopy type of the sets $M_t$ indicates the presence of critical points for some function $f_t$.

Let $u$ denote the generator (of degree $2$) of the cohomology $H^*(BS^1; \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}[u]$ of the classifying space of $S^1$. We define the following index:

$$l(t) := \text{ind}_u M_t$$.

Assuming that the family $f_t$ is decreasing, Théret shows that the function $l : [0,1] \to \mathbb{N}$ has the following properties.

1. $l$ is increasing;
2. $l$ is locally constant around regular values;
3. if $t_0^- < t_0^+$ and $l(t_0^-) \neq l(t_0^+)$, then the segment $[t_0^-, t_0^+]$ admits a value $t_0$ such that $f_{t_0}$ has a non-trivial critical cone;
4. if $l(t_0^+) > l(t_0^-) + 1$, and if $t_0 \in [t_0^-, t_0^+]$ is an isolated critical value, then $f_{t_0}$ has infinitely many distinct critical cones.

As an application, Théret proved (by means of generating functions as developed by Viterbo) that any Hamiltonian diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{C} P^n$ has at least $n+1$ fixed points (which is the minimal number of critical points of a function on $\mathbb{C} P^n$).

---

There exist different indicators that provide information on the topology of the manifold $M$. In particular, one can look at the dimension of its cohomology, the sum of its Betti numbers $BS(M)$, its Lusternik-Schnirelmann category $LS(M)$, its cup-length $CL(M)$, and the minimal number of critical points $\text{Crit}(M)$ of a function on $M$. A lot is known regarding the relations between these indicators. For instance, we have:

1. $\text{Crit}(M) \geq LS(M) \geq CL(M)$;
2. $BS(M) \geq CL(M)$;
3. $\text{dim} M \geq LS(M)$;

Another way to define a cohomological index if $M$ is a $G$-space is the following:
$$\widetilde{\text{ind}}(X) := \text{dim} Im ( f^* : H^*(BG) \to H^*(X_G)),$$
where $f : X_G \hookrightarrow M_G \to BG$ is the classifying map of $X$. Both indices $\text{ind}$ and $\widetilde{\text{ind}}$ were studied for instance in Givental's non-linear generalization of the Maslov index.

---

Here are my questions:

1. What is the relation between $\text{ind}$ and $\widetilde{\text{ind}}$ ?
2. When / why is it more convenient to prefer using one instead of the other ?
3. How are these indices related to $CL$, $LS$, $BS$ ?
4. Can we say something about the change of $CL(M_t)$, $LS(M_t)$, $BS(M_t)$ when $t$ crosses a critical value (cf. example of $\mathbb{C} P^n$) without assuming that the functions $f_t$ are Morse ?

A negative answer to this last question would imply that the indices defined above are more adapted to the study of critical point sets, but I would like to understand why.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a few points in your question which are a bit confusing. In your first definition of $\operatorname{ind}_\alpha$, what is the map $M\to BG$ if $M$ is just a $G$-manifold (such a map corresponds to a principal $G$ bundle over $M$). It think your inequality 3 is the wrong way round (LS cateogory is bounded *above* by dimension). Also, what is $X$ in your definition of $\widetilde{\operatorname{ind}}$?

Comment: Thank for your remarks @Mark. I'm sorry for the confusion, let me change these points.

Comment: All changed, sorry again. The index $\widetilde{\text{ind}}$ is defined as the dimension of the image of the homomorphism induced by the classifying map in cohomology, as written above.

Comment: A trivial observation is that $\widetilde{\operatorname{ind}}\geq\operatorname{ind}$ (up to a normalisation constant). Are you familiar with the equivariant LS-category (introduced by Marzantowicz)? It seems like these indices should be lower bounds for that, but I haven't found a reference. Also, there is the Fadell-Husseini ideal valued index (the kernel of the classifying map in cohomology) which seems to me at least to be more common than the indices you describe.